# Create a new list with fields of 2 entities

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, lambda

I have 2 entities being them: `Employees` and `SendMessage`:

```
public class Employee
{
    [DbColumn(IsIdentity =true, IsPrimary =true)]
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string Date_Birth { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string Home_Address { get; set; }

    [DbColumn]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public long ShiftId { get; set; }
}
```

**As you can see the EmployeeId field is to connect the two**

```
public class MessageSent
{
    [DbColumn(IsIdentity =true, IsPrimary =true)]
    public long MessageSentId { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public long MessageSentSeq { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [DbColumn]
    public string DateSent { get; set; }

}
```

To redeem I use the following method

```
gvEmployee.DataSource = new EmployeeService().GetAll();
```

Now comes my need I need to show on my new screen the following fields:
`MessageSentId,EmployeeId,MessageSentSeq` of the table `MessageSent` **and**  `Name,Surname` of the table `Employees`.

How can I create a third list with these 5 fields to fill my grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your employees:

```
var employees = new EmployeeService().GetAll();
```

Then your messages:

```
var messages = new MessageSentService().GetAll(); // probably like this, idk what its in your code
```

Using the LINQ query syntax is much clearer, more natural, and makes it easier to spot errors:

```
var query = 
    from employee in employees
    join message in messages
    on employee.EmployeeId equals message.EmployeeId 
    select new { 
        MessageSentId = message.MessageId,
        EmployeeId = message.EmployeeId,
        MessageSentSeq = message.MessageSentSeq,
        Name = employee.Name,
        Surname = employee.Surname
    };
```

Then you can use `query` and its fields.

Comment: @Will You said yo take employees like `new EmployeeService().GetAll();` so set it to variable: `var employees = new EmployeeService().GetAll();` and then change `database.Employees` with `employees`, do the same with messages

Comment: @Will updated answer, hope this could lead you to solution

Comment: Perfect! Now I suit my needs with filters. Thank you very much @Mark!